# PHP import CSV file and use data as variables

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I would like to import a CSV document and parse its content to use it as variables. The document would always have fixed column names and column numbers. Any examples would be excellent.

I could only find a parse that shows the contents of the CSV file:

```
<?PHP

/**
 * parse-csv.php
 */

$err_upTmpName = 'csvfiletutorial.csv';

$row = 0;

if (($handle = fopen($err_upTmpName, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if($row == 0){ 
        $row++; 
        } else {

            // $data[0] = first name; $data[1] = last name; $data[2] = email; $data[3] = phone

            if(!empty($data[0]) && !empty($data[1])) echo $data[0].' - '.$data[1].' - '.$data[2].' - 
'.$data[3].' - '.$data[4].'<br/>';

        }

    }

} else {

    echo 'File could not be opened.';
}   

fclose($handle);

   ?>
```

**Input sample csv:**
 date,value,value2
     4.10.2019,15,10

**Desired output csv:** 
using values from CSV file in a formula for example: 15+10
output= 
date,sum_values
4.10.2019,25

output gets saved to a new CSV file

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parse its content to use it as variables"?

Comment: You've already have the content in `$data` variable in your code. Just use it how you need instead of echoing it.

Comment: Add some sample input and desired output.

Comment: @freeek see post edit.

Comment: @mnm but you have all the needed input in `$data`, whats the problem doing needed operations with this array and put the result back using `fputcsv`?